# Get substring between two strings PHP - Reading HTML

Tags: php, html, string

I am having a ton of trouble running through finding a string between two strings.

This is the code i currently have

```html
<?

$html = file_get_contents('mywebsite');

$tags = explode('<',$html);

foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
  // skip scripts
  if (strpos($tag,'script') !== FALSE) continue;
  // get text
  $text = strip_tags('<'.$tag);
  // only if text present remember
  if (trim($text) != '') $texts[] = $text;
  
  //print_r($text);
 echo($text);
 
 
}


function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
 $string = " ".$string;
 $ini = strpos($string,$start);
 if ($ini == 0) return "";
 $ini += strlen($start);   
 $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
 return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = $text;
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "tag1", "tag2");

print_r($parsed);

echo ($parsed);

?>
```

I think the problem happens on this line:

```
$fullstring = $text;
```

I am not entirely sure if $text has the stripped down HTML from the above function.  When i run this code i get the stripped out webpage like i expect but i got nothing between the tags i am setting.

Does anyone know why this might be happening or what i am missing?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to return the string in between the two "tags" i have.

Comment: While we could just help you with the original question, your code begs the question what is the end goal? There are much better tools available for parsing html depending on what you want to do.

Comment: basically what i am doing in the first part is getting a website and stripping it down removing tags etc. then i am saving it as $text.  I then want to pass this to my get string between function so i can find the text between two strings that i specify.  I hope this clears it up

Comment: have you checked if your get_string_between() is working correctly with arbitrary inputs ?

Comment: don't use string operations on HTML markup. Use HTML Parsers, they are made for the purpose of parsing HTML

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you gave an explicit example of what you'd like your output to be when given an input.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon I am trying to find text on a webpage.  I am admittedly pretty new to php and so i have been scavenging the web trying to find ways to do this.  Above is what i have found that has gotten me the closest to my goal.  http://www.titantv.com/ i want to be able to find the current program on a given channel.  Using the above code i can enter in "A&E-W"0 for the first tag and "(" for the second tag and it should return the current show name.  However, nothing is returned.

Comment: If you run the above code you will see the output you get and what you would expect the tags to be for A&E as an example to get the current show which i believe is what is right after A&E but i could be wrong.

Comment: @TamimAdDari yes i have checked the code by entering a string like "this is a super fun test" and setting the tags as "a" and "fun"  When i do that super is returned as expected

Comment: @Ghost can you give me an example what you are talking about please.

Comment: @user3205214 check this for HTML parsing in PHP: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ & http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you are declaring text as a local variable inside for loop. so , after when you are assigning $text to fullstring It's actually null. I don't understand what you are trying to do , but do this and see if it works

```
$fullstring = ""
foreach ($tags as $tag){
    #your code as usual
    echo($text);
    $fullstring = $fullstring.$text;
}
```

and delete the `$fullstring = $text` line.

Comment: thank you that solved my problem!  I would upvote your answer but i do not have enough reputation.  How should i rephrase my question if i am able to edit it so it will help more people looking for this simple problem?

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct answer by ticking the 'right' mark.

Comment: and you can edit the title as "Getting null string while assigning a string after for loop".  By the way , its pretty subjective , so think how did you searched for the problem in  google , and make a title like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'this is my [tag]dog[/tag]';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '[tag]', '[/tag]');

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

[Reference](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/)